# ¿Como hacer que al dar clic en un registro de una tabla me actualice los datos de un formulario con los datos del registro correspondiente con ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

tengo una tabla en la cual se muestran todos los registros de una tabla de la bd y en la cual al dar click se debe mostrar la informacion del registro seleccionado en el formulario pues en este siempre se muestra el primer registro, ademas que todo lo de la pagina siga funcionando perfectamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi pagina y a lo que me refiero que siga funcionando lo demas de la pagina es el menu principal son dropdowns los cuales permite seleccionar un archivo, el boton de las 3 barras es para compactar el menu principal, y donde dice el nombre martin damian y un punto verde es para cerrar sesion, ademas de los botones NUEVO, EDITAR y ELIMINAR sigan funcionando correctamente

----CODIGO TABLA DE VENDEDORES-----

```
<div class="box-body" style="height:380px; overflow:auto">
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No. Vendedor</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>  
                <th>RFC</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            while($fila=sqlsrv_fetch_array($consultaVendedores)){
                $numVende=$fila['no_vende'];
                $nom=$fila['nombre'];
                $rfc=$fila['rfc'];
            ?>
            <tr id="fila" onclick="alerta(<?php echo $numVende;?>);"  >
                <th id="no_vende" ><?php echo $numVende; ?></th>
                <th id="nombre"><?php echo $nom; ?></th>
                <th id="rfc"><?php echo $rfc; ?></th>
            </tr>       
            <?php 
                }
            ?>      
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

----CODIGO FUNCION ALERTA----

```
function alerta(id){
   $("#info").load('datosVende.php?id='+id);
}
```

el div info es todo lo del centro

Comment: Son ventanas distintas, recargas página?....

Comment: mmm a que te refieres? disculpa soy algo nuevo en esto y pues no se bien los terminos jejeje

Comment: lo que hago es que vuelvo a poner casi todo el codigo en otro archivo el cual es datosvende.php

Answer (score 1):

A cada elemento de la tabla, deberías asignarle un `ID` o un `class`, que te facilite conocer el campo por el que filtrar en la base de datos.

Luego por `JQUERY`, podrías hacer la lectura del identificador, para abrir la ventana que deseas

Comment: hago esto
<tr id="fila" onclick="alerta(<?php echo $numVende;?>);"  >
      <th id="no_vende" ><?php echo $numVende; ?></th>
      <th id="nombre"><?php echo $nom; ?></th>
      <th id="rfc"><?php echo $rfc; ?></th></tr>

Comment: function alerta(id){
   $("#info").load('datosVende.php?id='+id);  }

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código en ella

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tienes php en embebido en tu código html pero tienes una función que parece estar utilizando jQuery. No te puedo ayudar haciéndolo con php pero sé hacerlo en jQuery. 
Sería mejor si no les pones id="fila" a las filas que creas dinámicamente a través de php porque un id es único. sería mejor que lo pusieras como una clase.

Primero, deberías hacer una función que al hacer click el vendedor haga una llamada al servidor con ajax o a través de una promesa y filtre los resultados para sólo tener el que corresponda al id que tienes seleccionado. Voy a usar el rfc del vendedor como ejemplo para identificar a uno de entre toda tu base de datos.

Podría ser algo así:

```
$('tr.list').click(function(e){ 
    var vendedorSeleccionado = $(e.target).find('th.rfc').text(); //esto será un string
    //aquí llamas al servidor, bajas la info de los vendedores, filtras y el vendedor correcto lo envías a otra función encargada de desplegar la info        
    $.Promise($.post({url: 'endpoint/data/base'})).then(function(data){
                //data debería ser un array de objetos
                data.map(function(item, index){
                    if( item[rfc] === vendedorSeleccionado)
                    { desplegarInfo(item); }
                });
      });
 });

    function desplegarInfo(vendedor){
     //aquí podrías tener seleccionados los elementos donde vas a desplegar 
    //la info en un array, que creo que son inputs (parece que en 
    //realidad es la interfaz de registro de vendedores, donde se puede editar
    // su info, así que recomiendo que afectes su placeholder para que te 
    //aparezca esa info por default. si el orden de los elementos del array es 
    //el mismo que la info que viene en el objeto 'vendedor' que será pasado a 
    //la función puedes hacerlo a través de un loop (incluso si las claves 
    //tienen el mismo nombre que el id de los elementos en el array, pero 
    //tendrás que relacionarlos primero en ese caso
       var elementosDondeDesplegar = [$('input#nombreVendedor'), $('input#noVendedor'), $('input#rfcVendedor'), .... todos los elementos que necesites];
       Object.keys(vendedor).forEach(function(item, index){
            var currentElement = elementosDondeDesplegar[index];
            //currentElement siempre será un elemento distinto del array, cambiando progresivamente. vendedor[item] te va a dar el valor de la correspondiente key del objeto. que si está en el mismo orden que el array de elementos lo pondrá como el valor del placeholder.
            currentElement.attr('placeholder', vendedor[item]);
       });
    }
```

Algo así debería ser las funciones que te ayuden. espero te sirva

Comment: entonces esta linea <tr id="fila" onclick="alerta(<?php echo $numVende;?>);"  > quedaria asi? <tr class="list">

Answer (score 0):

Pues lo que puedes hacer es la `class=box-body` cambiarla por `id=box-body` y con *AJAX* mandar a llamar un *PHP* que construya otra vez la tabla con la consulta del registro seleccionado. Ingresas la tabla realizada en *PHP* con el siguiente código en *AJAX*:

```
peticion.onreadystatechange = function( ) {
  if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 )
    document.getElementById( "box-body" ).innerHTML = this.responseText;
};

peticion.open( "GET", url_php, true);
peticion.send( );
```